# pandas dataframe insert rows with mapping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It's probably very simple, but I'm pretty new with python dataframe.

I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
str={}
df = pd.DataFrame(str,columns=['ID','NAME','DESC'])
df1= pd.DataFrame(str,columns=['ID_NEW','NAME_NEW','DESC_NEW'])

df = df.append({'ID':'2','NAME':'CCC','DESC':'DDD'} ,ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.append({'ID_NEW':'1','NAME_NEW':'AAA','DESC_NEW':'BBB'} ,ignore_index=True)
```

I want to insert all rows from dataframe "df" to "df1" with mapping: id -> id_new, name - > name_new,desc->desc_new

So the result of df1 will be after insert:

```
print(df1.to_string(index=False))


ID_NEW NAME_NEW DESC_NEW
     1      AAA      BBB
     2      CCC      DDD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column names match, you can pretty easily just concatenate the two dataframes:

```
In [61]: pd.concat([df1, df.rename(columns={c: f"{c}_NEW" for c in df.columns})])
Out[61]:
  ID_NEW NAME_NEW DESC_NEW
0      1      AAA      BBB
0      2      CCC      DDD
```

You can assign `df1 =` that to overwrite it with the concatenated frame.

Comment: Ok, one way is to rename column. But it is not possible to say(map) which source column have to be mapped to which target column??

Comment: That's what the `.rename` is doing - mapping source to target columns. If it's not a simple addition of just appending `_NEW` to the end of the columns as it is here, you can just specify something else in the `columns=` dict.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I quite understand the question, but maybe you are looking to do something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID_NEW','NAME_NEW','DESC_NEW'])
df1.loc[len(df1.index)] = ['1', 'AAA', 'BBB']
df1.loc[len(df1.index)] = ['2', 'CCC', 'DDD']

print(df1.to_string(index=False))
```

Alternatively, if you are just trying to concatenate two data frames, you can do something like this -

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_NEW': ['1'],
                    'NAME_NEW': ['AAA'],
                    'DESC_NEW': ['BBB']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_NEW': ['2'],
                    'NAME_NEW': ['CCC'],
                    'DESC_NEW': ['DDD']})

frames = [df1, df2]

df3 = pd.concat(frames)

print(df3.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: No, I have two dataframes with different column name, like I wrote in my example.If I have same column name it is easy. I want to insert all rows from one to another with column mapping (id->id_new etc)